# Parse single column result set into multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop, pivot, temp-tables

I've written a stored procedure that is returning a 2 column temp table, one ID column that is not unique, but a value between 2 and 12 to group values on.  The other column is that actual data value column.  I want to break out this 1 column table into a table into basically 1 table of 11 columns, 1 column for each dataset.

[image]

i'd like to have this parsed out into columns by ID.  An identity column is not necessary since they will be unique to their own column.  Something like;

```
Data2        Data3        Data4
102692...    103516....   108408....
104114...    103476....   108890....
```

and so on.  I have tried using a While Loop through the datasets, but it's mainly getting these contained in 1 insert that is troubling me. I can't figure out how to say

```
While recordCount > 0
    Begin
        Insert into @tempTable(value1ID2,value1ID3,Value1ID4)
    End
```

and then loop through value2ID2, value2ID3 etc.

If this isn't attainable that's fine i'll have to figure out a workaround, but the main reason i'm trying to do this is for a Report Builder dataset for a line chart that will eventually share a date grouping.

Comment: The expression `@tempTable` implies SQL Server, so I'm removing the MySQL tag.

Comment: alright, i had just had the SQL tag, but it suggested mySQL, that's my mistake. thank you

Comment: i just did a quick search on pivots and it seems you're exactly correct, i'm going to work up a solution, thanks for the suggestion.  Shows my lack of SQL knowledge, but we're learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to aggregate string values, then you will need to use either the `max` or `min` aggregate function.  The problem with that is it will return a single row for each column.  In order to rerun multiple rows, then you will need to use a windowing function like `row_number()` to generate a unique value for each `id`/`string` combination.  This will allow you to return multiple rows for each `id`:

```
select Data2 = [2], Data3 = [3], Data4 = [4]
from
(
    select id, stringvalue,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by stringvalue) seq
    from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
    max(stringvalue)
    for id in ([2], [3], [4])
) piv
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i was actually reading a different post with your answer accepted for this and trying to create my query off of it when i received this so this was extremely helpful! thanks again

Comment: this is always going to order from Max to min isn't it?  Is there any way to get around that or no?  It doesn't seem as though since an aggregate has to be used, it's just I need these values in their order since they are simulated values that need to match dates i have saved.

Comment: @NickG Pivot requires an aggregate function -either max or min for a string -- the order is determined by the `row_number()` order by.  If you have some other value to order it then you can use that. Without seeing all of your data it's tough, but if you generated this via a date then you might be able to create the row number at the same time you create the rest of your data and just order by your date